# Is it possible to use checkbox menu functionality using dc 2.1.9?

Tags: dc.js

I am using dc 2.1.9 and i have not updated my dashboard with recent version of dc just because i need to do lot of syntax changes to my code. 
 My question here is whether i can use the checkbox functionality using my old version of dc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [original pull request](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1348) for this feature was directed at dc.js 2.0.

You should be able to copy and paste the class into a copy of dc.js 2.0.

[Here is the relevant part of the pull request](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1348/files#diff-7dc7e6020cb53b43b5397330e4dc33d2).

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks much Gordon. Just one last thing, so all the dc.js charts in the examples (https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/) can be used using dc.js 2.0 versions?

Comment: You'd have to look at the release notes and search the pull requests to figure out what things were contributed when. There were [at least 4 charts merged into 3.0](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/Changelog.md#300); I think most of them were contributed to 2.0 and then upgraded before merging. Of course, you'll also miss out on any bug fixes since then.